# Are binary splits always better than multi-way splits in decision trees?

Tags: classification, cart, entropy

I'm trying to devise a decision tree for classification with multi-way split at an attribute but even though calculating the entropy for a multi-way split gives better information gain than a binary split, the decision tree in code never tries to split in a multi-way.
I was also wondering if entropy for binary splits for a categorical attribute can be smaller than that of a multi-way split, because till now all multi-way splits have provided lesser entropy than binary splits (my dataset has categorical attributes only).

Comment: The Quinlan family of tree algorithms (as opposed to CART) do perform multi-way splits for categorical features.

Comment: @Sycorax the question has the cart tag, so I don't think your answer was wrong...

Comment: Note that the sample size for such trees to be reproducible/stable is enormous.